# Any charts/bots out there for volumes going from private/unknown wallets to known exchanges?

Tags: charts, bots, live-data, tools

To figure out if whales are suddenly moving their BTC or USDT etc from their private/unknown wallets to known exchanges. Or vice versa, if they're comfortable enough to move a lot back onto their wallets.

Or at least how much money is currently on exchanges vs global crypto cap, plotted onto a chart.

Bonus points if there is a way to know how old the private/unknown wallets are. So for ex if wallets from 6 years ago are suddenly moving BTC to an exchange, vs wallets made e.g. this year.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out WhaleWatch on Twitter. This account posts the exact kind of thing you’re looking for- specifically for BTC and USDT. They differentiate between wallet to wallet and exchange to wallet etc. They post data live and the amount too. There are other accounts just like it on Twitter but they’re a good place to start.

Comment: Yeah, you mean @whale_alert, the free/public version is limited to super large transactions only, and twitter text (no charts). There's also glassnode.com, but both of these are behind a paywall if you want to actually see a chart. And the price is not worth it imo if you just want this stuff. Should be public information. I might just find some github repo to fork and implement this myself if I get too much time on my hands.